# Глубокое кэширование даных

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Можно ли как-нибудь данные сохранять во `vuex` так, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы они оставались в кэше. Например, у меня есть курсы и после того, как они прилетели с бэка, я сохранил их туда. Во время перезагрузки страницы они потеряются и буду ещё раз запрошены. Как этого можно избежать?

Comment: localSgtorage, IndexDb

Comment: @Дмытрык вы можете дать подробный ответ и я его зачту

Comment: `Можно ли как-нибудь данные сохранять во vuex так, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы они оставались в кэше.`. Вариант кеширования запросов в браузере рассматривали? Я про `Cache-Control`. Не подходит? Почему?

Comment: Если кратко, на сервере нужно выставить `Cache-Control` и удалить если есть `Expires` и `Pragma`. В dev косоли Сети будет видно "from disk cache", 0ms. Для разработки можно включить "No cache" чтобы бек дергался постоянно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Экземпляры Vuex не предоставляют хуков создания и разрушения хранилища.

Но можно сохранять и восстанавливать состояние хранилища в хуках жизненного цикла корневого экземпляра Vue:

```
new Vue({
  // ... 
  store, 
  // ... 
  created() {
    const savedState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state') || 'null'); 
    if (savedState) this.$store.replaceState(savedState); 
  }, 
  beforeDestroy() {
    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(this.$store.state)); 
  }
});
```

---

Это сработает, если хранилище разрушается после отработки `beforeDestroy` - так должно быть по логике вещей, но я не проверял.
Если же логика иная, и разрушение `store` все-таки происходит раньше - сохранять состояние можно либо по таймеру (в `setInterval` установленным в хуке `mounted`), либо "ручным" вызовом метода (перенеся в метод код из хука `beforeDestroy`).

Comment: К сожалению, сниппеты SO не позволяют использовать `localStorage`.

Comment: На работе пауза? :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, Да, был перерыв на завтрак)) А в общем и целом, загруз до февраля примерно .